# Analyzing grades across classes whose distributions differ

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, standardization, median, quantile-regression

Let's say I have grade data for 5 classes of students. I also know some information about each student in each of those classes from a survey (gender, age, grade level, etc.). I want to know if a given characteristic (e.g., gender) is correlated with the grade the student gets, on average. So far so good--this suggests a regression of some kind.

However, the classes are not all equally easy/hard, so the means/medians of the grade distributions in each class are different. A score of 82 might be above average in one class and well below average in another. This indicates that these data cannot all be treated as the same across courses in their raw forms.

I see multiple ways of approaching this question from here.

1. Standardize all the values within classes, either by subtracting the
   mean score and dividing by the standard deviation or by subtracting
   the median and dividing by the interquartile range. Then, do the
   regression on these standardized values, with the regression telling
   me how much a factor influences grade score relative to the average/median
   grade in a course.
2. Make the regression a mixed model and add class in as a grouping/random variable that adjusts the intercept, essentially letting every class "start" in a different place but otherwise assume the relationships between each factor and grade occur the same way irrespective of that starting point.
3. Do a quantile regression of some kind? I think here a standardization within class would still be necessary...

Which of these approaches would be the most straight-forward and defensible? What factors beyond those I have already laid out should I be considering?

I should mention my motivation for asking this question: Our proposed approach to analyzing these data was to turn the outcome into a binary variable for every student--Grade above the median course grade vs. grade below the median course grade. Then, we would analyze the data using a logistic regression. However, this feels like a wasteful approach to me and it seems like one or more of the above directions might be superior.

Comment: I would use approach number 1 - Standardizing all grades. It's the simplest and easiest to explain.

Comment: Are the same students taking all (or at least some) of the classes? That would introduce dependence which will have to be treated.  Maybe look into IRT? IRT=Item Response Theory